# Package pgfplots Error: could not retrieve column

Tags: pgfplots

I have a `csv` file named "aaa.csv" whose content is:

```
aa,bb,cc
1,1,1
2,2,4
3,3,9
4,4,16
```

I make plot with the data in this file by `pgfplots`. But my code fails to compile. The following message is given:

```
ERROR: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, could not retrieve column 'aa' 
from table 'aaa.csv'. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..
```

What's wrong with my code?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xtick=data,
    xticklabels from table={aaa.csv}{aa},
    width=.9\textwidth,
    title=test,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=0,xmin=0,
]
\addplot [red,mark=*,] table[col sep=comma,x=bb,y=cc] {aaa.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell the plot earlier that your data is using a comma as separator:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots,pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xtick=data,
    table/col sep=comma,
    xticklabels from table={aaa.csv}{aa},
    width=.9\textwidth,
    title=test,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$y$},
    ymin=0,xmin=0,
]
\addplot [red,mark=*,] table[x=bb,y=cc] {aaa.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is `table` before `col sep=comma`! That's it! I once tried 'col sep=comma'  but failed. Thank you very much for your suggestion!